# bash sh differences, script conversion

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu, sh

I have this script that was written in bash

```
#!/bin/sh

# script makes grep directly on dmesg output
# looking  for  'USB disconnect'  phrase  if
# it  finds  it  then  machine  is  rebooted
# ver 1.2
clear

UNPLUG_MESSAGE="PLEASE UNPLUG THE USB STICK NOW"
echo $UNPLUG_MESSAGE && sleep 2

while true; do

USB_STATUS=`dmesg | tail -n 5 |  grep 'disconnect'`

  if [[ $USB_STATUS == *USB?disconnect* ]]
     then
        clear && echo "Rebooting... bye" 
    sleep 1 && sudo reboot

  elif [[ $USB_STATUS != *USB?disconnect* ]]
     then
        clear && echo "Please remove USB drive..."
        sleep 2
  fi
done

exit 0
```

After changing #!/bin/bash to #!/bin/sh, the script does not work any more - what should I change in this script?

I got errors like unknown operand *USB?disconnect*, ./reboot.sh: 16: ./reboot.sh: [[: not found, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On ubuntu `sh` is [`dash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) (you can run `ls -l $(which sh)` to see this).

In [`dash`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/dash) there is no `[[` (*double brackets*) operator. You have to use the `test` builtin function or `[`  (*single brackets*) only.

You can replace:

```
if [[ $USB_STATUS == *USB?disconnect* ]]
...
elif [[ $USB_STATUS != *USB?disconnect* ]]
```

By:

```
if [ $(echo $USB_STATUS | grep -c "USB disconnect") != 0 ]
...
elif [ $(echo $USB_STATUS | grep -c "USB disconnect") = 0 ]
```

Comment: It's even simpler to use the exit status of `grep` directly: `if echo "$USB_STATUS" | grep -q "USB disconnect"; then` (note that `grep -q` doesn't output anything, it just exits with a success status if it finds a match).

Comment: Or use the little-known `expr` command to do the regular expression matching: `if expr "$USB_STATUS" : "USB disconnect" > /dev/null; then`. This saves a process over the pipeline. ("Forgotten" rather than "little-known", perhaps. The rest of its functionality has been added to the POSIX shell via the `$((...))` arithmetic expression.)